# Talend pivot columns

Tags: java, sql, pivot, talend

I am using `ttPivotToColumnsDelimited` to pivot a row to a column and it's working well. The problem is that I can pivot only one row with this component and I need to pivot 2 rows at the same time. Can anyone please give the solution even if I should write in java or SQL?

Comment: Could you show us what you tried ? , do you have multiple rows with the same schema ?

Comment: I have only one table and I want to transpose two rows of this table into columns, on tPivotToColumnsDelimited we can transpose a single row in the parameters, so how can I transpose the two rows without doing a double tPivotToColumnsDelimited.